# Whats causing these lighting effects?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to light a hall. Therefore I am putting some lights on the ceiling.
First I tried with point lights and now with spots directed to the ground.
So I have a row with 4 lights, then copied them and moved them few meters down. ( see gif )
Somehow it looks like only 4 lights can be active at the same time, as I move, differnt lights become active.

I really don't know what's causing these effects...

[image]

Comment: Does it also happen in the GameView?

Comment: Yes, and it looks like it's only affecting the plane itself. walls are lit up ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a guess but you probably have to increase the [`Project Settings -> Quality -> Pixel Light Count`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QualitySettings-pixelLightCount.html)

> The maximum number of pixel lights that should affect any object.
>
> If there are more lights illuminating an object, the dimmest ones will be rendered as vertex lights.

Click on the Quality level you want to edit and adjust

[image]

See also [What’s the visual difference between Pixel & Vertex lighting?](https://unity3d.college/2017/07/06/pixel-vertex-lights-unity3d/#:%7E:text=What%27s%20the%20visual%20difference%20between,vertex%20and%20interpolate%20between%20them.)

---

Specific for the URP this might also help [Setting up the Rendering Pipeline and Lighting in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BestPracticeLightingPipelines.html) where it says e.g. for Lights

> Max # of Lights: 1 Direction + 8(4 on gles2) lights

Comment: i don't have this option, but my quality profile is set to ultra.  Also I found out, that the walls are lit up correctly, only the plane is not lit up. I scaled the plane to fit the hall, maybe that can cause troubles.

Comment: Note from the second link that apparently even in `Ultra` the default PixelLightCount is `4` which would explain why there are always only `4` spots

Comment: Yep, but why don't i have this option? I am using the universal render pipeline. So change all lights to important will also have no effect. But, relating to your link,  all other lights should be vertex lights then, and I should see something if I understand this right.

Comment: Well I'm not sure how URP and in particular the shader you are using treats Vertex Lightning or if this option is even valid then ... It would probably need to support the [Vertex Lit Rendering Path](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RenderTech-VertexLit.html)

Comment: Ok, in graphics settings there was a universal renderer set which hides the pixel setting...  Now need to fix textures as automatic upgrading doesnt work ...

Comment: Works  now thanks. But I don't get if the pixel light is not active, why don't I see vertex lighting?